# Connecting two IPs like an URL

Tags: ip, isp, net

I haven't found answer anywhere, so here comes the question.
My ISP connected me to a router with thousands of other clients, so my public IP is the same as many others. And I want to make a small private server which can be accessible across whole web.
So my home router shows me IP 10.x.x.x and actually my public IP is 89.x.x.x. Is there any way to reach the IP 10.x.x.x from the Internet?
Yeah I thought the same about IPv6 but it's still not accessible for me ;[

Comment: Wait, your public IP address is shared across many people? Your ISP is doing ISP-level NAT? If so, you'll need to ask your ISP if they'll do port forwarding, but most likely you're out of luck. This is why ISPs doing NAT is bad.

Comment: What choice does the ISP have? In many parts of the world it is no longer possible to obtain enough IPv4 addresses. This is why the IPv6 migration is so important.

Comment: While the ISP doesn't necessarily have any choice, I'm optimistic that  czesuaf has some choice around what ISP they use :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be in a country where IP addresses are in very short supply. This is the only reason that an ISP would deploy large-scale NAT at its customers. Hopefully your ISP is also smart and is planning to deploy IPv6 as quickly as possible.

You won't be able to accept incoming connections and run a home server at all in a scenario in which the ISP uses large-scale NAT. And many other applications may not work 100% reliably, such as instant messaging, Skype, etc.

If you want to be able to run services on your connection, you will probably have to pay for business-class service with a static IP (IPv4) address. Be prepared to pay a high premium for this.

If you just want to run a small server for some little project, your best and cheapest option is probably to just lease a virtual server from a company in the US or EU. You can often find these for just a few dollars/euros a month at places like [lowendbox.com](http://lowendbox.com/). This will almost certainly be cheaper than trying to run it at home on a business ADSL/cable connection, though you'll have to shop carefully as low-end providers vary greatly in the quality of service they provide.

Comment: Yeah, I know, BUT interesting thing that some of my friends pay normally for the Internet and have their own IPv4.

Comment: They either have a different ISP, or they are an old customer and haven't had their IP taken away yet. It'll happen sooner or later...